# How to preserve the value in arrays in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I made 2 classes in App_code folder. In Class1 I declare some int,string and double type array (like double[] abc) and I wrote a method to fill the value in those arrays. I use these values to show on gridview on default.aspx page. Now when i want use these value again in my Class2, I got to those array null. I think I load the aspx page so these variable get refreshed. So now How can i preserved the value, so i use them again. I don't know about Session.

Comment: I would suggest to do more reading on Session Management in ASP.NET. There are many ways to do it but what works best for you can't be answered

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities are these. You could use the [`Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28VS.100%29.aspx) (if the data is user-specific) or the [`Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) (if the data is to/can be shared between contexts).

These two things are used in largely the same ways, just with different accessibilities and lifetime control etc.

Comment: @dav_i Is that an answer? Doesn't fit in to my count of two suggestions. (;

Comment: @EmreAcar A ViewState would be an inappropriate place to put this data.

Comment: I tried but Session object is not visible in app_code folder class.

Comment: It is... `HttpContext.Current.Session`.

Comment: Can I access this session in another Class?